# Show Battery current status and changed automatically on increase or decrease

Tags: android, batterylevel

I Build a android app in which i want to show the current battery status.I searched and i found the code for battery status but it will display battery status in text form like battery level remaining 50%.but i want to show it as indicator like below image.how can i do this.
and i also want battery status automatically changed when its charging status increase or decrease.

code for battery status

```
package com.example.androidbatterypercentage;

  import android.os.BatteryManager;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
  import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.IntentFilter;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.widget.TextView;

     public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private TextView batteryPercent;
   private void getBatteryPercentage() {
    BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         context.unregisterReceiver(this);
         int currentLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
         int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
         int level = -1;
         if (currentLevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
             level = (currentLevel * 100) / scale;
          }
          batteryPercent.setText("Battery Level Remaining: " + level + "%");
      }
    };  
    IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
     registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
 }


     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      batteryPercent = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.batteryLevel);
      getBatteryPercentage();
  }


  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  }
```

xml file is

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context=".MainActivity">


  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is a problem there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there is the sample link for the current battery status.

1) [Display](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Display-battery-information-of-android-device) battery information of android device

2) [Get](http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-sdk-get-device-battery-information/) Device Battery Information

You can used the process in `thread`,`TimerTask` or `services` to get automatically

I hope this help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be notified of any battery changes you should create a `BroadcastReceiver` and listen to `ACTION_BATERY_CHANGED` intents. You can the change your TextView or image accordingly.